# Should I use static class within public class, or just a lone class

Tags: java, class, static, public

If I have a public class, call it `ClassA`, that requires another class, call it `ClassB`, and:
1) No other classes in my program require access to `ClassB`.
2) `ClassB` does not need static access to the state of `ClassA`.

If these two points hold, are there guidelines as to whether `ClassB` should be a `public static class ClassB {` *within* `public class ClassA {`, or whether `ClassB` should be a `class ClassB {` *outside* of `ClassA`?

Comment: Seems like a data interpretion question in general aptitute :p

Answer (score 2):

Since it's not gonna be used outside of `ClassA`, it's better to be:

```
private class ClassB {

}
```

Comment: Why `static` and not just `class`?

Answer (score 2):

Does `ClassB` do a definable, useful job independently of `ClassA`? If it is only part of the `ClassA` implementation, define it in `ClassA` as a private static class. If it has independent meaning, define it as a top level class, with either package or public access depending on the scope of its potential usefulness.

Answer (score 0):

Since ClassB does not need static access to the state of ClassA, classB can be private inner class.

> Non-static nested classes (inner classes) have access to other members
>   of the enclosing class, even if they are declared private. Static
>   nested classes do not have access to other members of the enclosing
>   class. As a member of the OuterClass, a nested class can be declared
>   private, public or protected.
>   (from javadoc)